# VSTS TFS Query all resolved task but not resolved by me and in current iteration

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

What is query for find all tasks/bugs which are

- resolved
- and in current iteration(sprint)
- and not resolved by me

[image]

Comment: The query is correct. What's the problem? Note: The Task work item type in CMMI process template has Resolved state. Regarding @CurrentIteration, it is the current active iteration, you can set the date for each iteration in team project admin page (e.g. https://XXX.visualstudio.com/[project]/_admin/_work)

Comment: Which process template you used (CMMI, Agile or Scrum)? What's the result of that query?

Answer (score 0):

The operator for State and Resolved By should be as **In Group**.

And the value for State should be `Resolved`, value for Resolved By as your `username`.

Then you will query the result as you expected.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for answer but what i want is all tasks **not** resolved by me and i tested **Not in group** for `Resolved By` and it didn't work

Comment: This (IN Group) will shows the work items which are not resolve by you.

Comment: And do you want to query all work items or only task? And task has not the Resolved state.